# Manual code coverage using jetty

Tags: java, jetty, code-coverage

Is there way for measure code coverage during unit testing/development. I am using jetty and would be possible to measure coverage in this?

thanks,
Mu2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answer mentions cobertura, but [jacoco](http://jacoco.org/jacoco/index.html) may be easier to set up.

It has a [java agent](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/agent.html), that can be easily appended to the VM running JETTY at startup by providing:

```
-javaagent:[yourpath/]jacocoagent.jar=[option1]=[value1],[option2]=[value2]
```